# CSS/HTML - iPhone Web App, targeting non-Retina only

Tags: html, css

My code is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme_retina.css" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2)">
```

And it works as expected, Retina devices use the retina CSS and non-retina use the normal CSS. But I would like a media addition to the non-retina link tag so that it will only be used for non-retina devices, and I have been looking and can't find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Won't this work?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme.css" media="only screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1)">
```

[This gist lists more](https://gist.github.com/1223963)

Comment: I think there are some devices between 1 and 2 (and probably will be higher than 2 in the future) so those devices would end up with no CSS at all in this case.